# django tastypie alter model fetching

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to find a way to make tastypie return results that are a little bit different than the default ones. For example, by default the api returns the following:

```
{
created_at: "2011-10-18T14:22:27",
email_address: "paul.mccartney@beatles.com",
first_name: "Paul",
id: 1,
is_active: true,
is_super_admin: true,
last_login: "2011-10-18T14:22:27",
last_name: "McCartney",
resource_uri: "/api/v1/user/1/",
updated_at: "2011-10-18T14:22:27",
username: "pmc"
}
```

And I would like to replace `first_name` and `last_name` with `full_name` being `Paul McCartney`. Is that possible to override model fields? If so - how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have to use the `dehydrate cicle`. [From the docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#the-dehydrate-cycle):

> Tastypie uses a “dehydrate” cycle to prepare data for serialization, which is to say that it takes the raw, potentially complicated data model & turns it into a (generally simpler) processed data structure for client consumption. This usually means taking a complex data object & turning it into a dictionary of simple data types.

I hope this helps!